# Restrict all FTP Accounts to a single directory

Tags: ftp, vsftpd, account-restrictions

I am trying to restrict all **FTP** users to the directory `/jannik` with the `vsftp-daemon`. I don't want them to go anywhere but the folder `/jannik` and it's sub-folders. Also, I don't want them to have write permission.

**What you should know:**

- I have the following common settings

  ```
  local_enable=yes
  write_enable=no
  ```
- I use a user blacklist to only allow one specific account to access the ftp (`userlist_deny=NO; userlist_enable=YES; userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.user_list`)
- In the `user_list` I've only one user (root)

**Again, what I would like to accomplish:**

- Only allow that user to access `/jannik` and all it's sub directories

**What I've tried to far:**

- Setting `local-root=/jannik` => This lets my ftp users all log on to the correct dir, but they can use `/../` in the URL to get out of the directory, letting them full access to all my files on the **VPS** server I own.
- Additionally setting `chroot_local_user=YES` gives me an error: *"500: OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writeable root inside chroot()"*

Do you have the idea, what could be wrong? I do ***not*** want to `chroot` their home directories, only to the given single directory.